# Instantiating a variable with Nothing, then assigning a New object instance

Tags: vb.net, coding-style

Looking through some old VB.Net code, I noticed a strange pattern that is making me scratch my head.

```
Dim objMyObject As Namespace.Child.ChildType = Nothing
objMyObject = New Namespace.Child.ChildType
```

(There is no additional code between the dimension and the assignment.)

It seems like the preferred style would be to do both on one line, or else skip the `= Nothing`.  As follows:

```
Dim objMyObject As Namespace.Child.ChildType = New Namespace.Child.ChildType
```

OR

```
Dim objMyObject As Namespace.Child.ChildType
objMyObject = New Namespace.Child.ChildType
```

OR, as suggested by @helrich

```
Dim objMyObject As New Namespace.Child.ChildType
```

Is there any particular value to doing it this way, or is this an instance of the original programmer being used to the VB6 way of doing things?

---

In VB6, dimensioning and instantiating a variable on one line was considered problematic because it would rerun the instantiation (if necessary) when the variable was accessed - effectively, a variable dimensioned in this way could never be tested for Nothing, because a new instance would be created on demand.  However, VB.Net does not preserve this convention.

Comment: Or even `Dim objMyObject As New Namespace.Child.ChildType`.

Comment: Nothing is null as you probably know. Initializing something to Nothing and declaring a variable (reference type) without assigning is the same thing.

Comment: it could be either a reflection of the original developer's *preference* or *ability level*.  If it is "old VB.Net code" maybe you could not do both in very very early versions (?) or again, they did not know you could.

Comment: This question is a bit pointless. I answered it by bearing in mind the differentiation declaration/instantiation between VB.NET and C# for example, for primitive types (Dim myString As String is fine vs, String myString = null; -> you have to assign a value). But what is the point in this specific context? You are dealing with a custom class and thus you have to instantiate it anyway! (in VB.NET too). It is clearly beecause of a personal coding routine although, in this specific case, with virtually no sense (the nothing bit does not instantiate). Thus you can safely remove all the nothings.

Comment: Helrich's commment is consisent with the [Visual Basic Coding Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h63fsef3.aspx).

Comment: @varocarbas - mainly, I want to ensure that there aren't any hidden traps if I choose to refactor this code.  Yes, it has to be instantiated anyway, so I also fail to see the value in the way it is currently written.  (I'm going to edit in some comments on why this pattern could have carried over from VB6.)

Comment: As I was writing in my answer (until realising that wasn't applicable here), it might be necessary if you use the given variable between the declaration and the instantiation and the default value of this class is different than nothing. For example: enum whose default value is "value1", but you want it to be nothing.   But, in this context, you cannot do anything with this variable before instantiating it and thus the nothing bit is irrelevant^2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is pointless.  The CLR already provides a hard guarantee that variables are initialized to Nothing.

It is otherwise completely harmless, the jitter optimizer will completely remove the code for the assignment.  So if the original author preferred that style then that's okay.  Maybe he was a former C# programmer that didn't understand the definite assignment rules in that language.  VB.NET does some checking too but it isn't nearly as strict.  Do check if this is a team standard that you are supposed to follow as well, hopefully not.

Comment: I hope not, too.  :)  The project has actually gone the other direction, from VB6 to VB.Net to C#.  Most of the remaining VB6/VB.Net code hasn't been touched in 7 or 8 years.

Comment: So does it mean that in C# it would  be required to do `Namespace.Child.ChildType myObj = null;` or would that be pointless as well?

Comment: It is not required in C#, the *new* statement counts as initialization.  So yes, pointless.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, there's no need to separate the declaration and assignment.

But I was wondering here (a hypothesis): Since you should split this way when you want to persist the variable in the stack when it is assigned in a code block (e.g: `If` statement), maybe once upon a time this block existed and it was removed keeping a constant association to it. 
Its association, though, was not merged with its declaration.

---

About associating `Nothing` to an empty variable: I personally like this pattern. :)

It tells myself (in future maintainances) that the variable was declared with an empty (null) value on purpose. It eliminates the doubt that I, maybe, forgot to write the `New` keyword behind the type.

Ahh, and it will also eliminate [a vb.net warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3fdk625a.aspx) during build.

Comment: This warning does not appear unless the variable is not assigned to any value at all. Also bear in mind the example I wrote in my comments above: one thing is something like Dim myString As String = Nothing (-> already instantiated; with or without the = Nothing) and a different thing is a class Dim myClass as myWholeClass = Nothing (-> it is NOT instantiated)

Comment: @varocarbas: You're right. But the warning may also appear in cases that "maybe" the var will not be assigned (that is, conditional assignment). The declaration + null assignment could be useful in `ReturnValidValueOrNull` method cases.

Comment: As I was saying in my (deleted) answer; I do like the = nothing (well... = something, ideally the right value), because I am used to write it in this way. But, really speaking, does not have any influence: VB.NET will make this variable Nothing independently upon what you write there.

Comment: @varocarbas: Right, agreed! :)